# Como faço para fazer o download do conteúdo de uma div?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Olá! Eu tenho na minha index:

```html
<div class="panel-body">
  <div id="teste"></div>
</div>
```

e tenho em um arquivo JS o seguinte:

```js
function downloadDiv(filename, elementId, mimeType) {

    if ($('#teste').html() == "") {

        swal("Erro!", "Teste está vazio.", "error");

    } else {

        var elementHtml = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"><style>.checker-hr {padding: 0px;margin: 0px;}</style>\n\n' + document.getElementById('#teste');
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        //mimeType = mimeType || 'text/plain';
        // nome do arquivo que vai ser baixado
        var fileName =  'teste.html';
    
        link.setAttribute('download', fileName);
        link.setAttribute('href', 'charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(elementHtml));
        link.click(); 

        swal("Sucesso!", "Foi feito o download de teste com sucesso!", "success");

    }

}
```

Minha ideia e fazer o download de tudo que tiver dentro do div "teste", porém isso não funciona. Alguém sabe o que eu posso ter feito de errado e como arrumar?

Comment: Não entendi o que você quer fazer. Sua `<div>` é vazia e o código parece ser uma tentativa de forçar o usuário a fazer um download não pretendido.

Comment: Foi apenas um exemplo. Vão ter itens na div, porém vão ser sempre itens diferentes, então preciso por pra fazer download, mas sempre da isso quando vou fazer o download: https://prnt.sc/r2ibfw

Comment: Coloque um [MCVE], porque ninguém vai ficar chutando se acerta ou não o que você fazer. Não importa se você está tentando fazer um DDA(driven download attack) apenas o código tem que refletir o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Por um código de JS com JQuery eu envio informações para dentro dessa Div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Há um erro de sintaxe nesta linha:

```
var elementHtml = ... + document.getElementById('#teste');
                                                 ↑
```

Não deve incluir o hash, apenas o nome da id:

```
var elementHtml = ... + document.getElementById('teste');
```

E para pegar o conteúdo interno do elemento, use `.innerHTML`:

```
var elementHtml = ... + document.getElementById('teste').innerHTML;
```

Você pode "baixar" o arquivo usando o objeto `Blob()` (funcionou no Chrome, Firefox e Opera atualizados. No IE11 e Edge não surtiu efeito. Como uso Windows, não testei no Safari). Na verdade você não está baixando nada. O script gera um pseudo-arquivo, inclui nele um conteúdo e abre a caixa de download pra você salvar.

```js
function downloadDiv(filename, elementId, mimeType) {

    if ($('#teste').html() == "") {

        console.log("Erro!", "Teste está vazio.", "error");

    } else {

        var elementHtml = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"><style>.checker-hr {padding: 0px;margin: 0px;}</style>\n\n' + document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML;
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        var file = new Blob([elementHtml], {type: mimeType});
        //mimeType = mimeType || 'text/plain';
        // nome do arquivo que vai ser baixado
        var fileName =  filename;
    
        link.setAttribute('download', fileName);
        link.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        link.click(); 

        console.log("Sucesso!", "Foi feito o download de teste com sucesso!", "success");

    }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-body">
  <div id="teste"><div style="color: red;">div interna</div></div>
</div>
<button onclick="downloadDiv('teste.html', 'teste', 'text/plain')">Baixar arquivo</button>
```